# how to fix hook to set state in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to have a user set a function variable with an input number. I have a form they enter a number into, which needs to set the **col** const up top.

So far, i am using a simple hook, and col *is* being set (i console logged it), but its not producing the desired array. Im thinking its something getting messed up in the toggling at the bottom of the code.

```
function DataFrame(){

  const [toggle, setToggle] = React.useState(false);
  const [col, setCol] = useState(0)
  var element = <li class="element"/>
  var row = 3
  var arr = []
  var i
  for (i = 0; i<row; i++){
    arr.push(element)
  }

  const Element = () => <li className="element" />;
  console.log(col)
  return (

    <div>
      <div >

        <div style={{fontFamily:'PressStart2P',opacity:'45%', width:'360px',
        position:'absolute',left:'36px', top: '160px',color:'rgb(143, 0, 145)'}}>
        </div>

        <div >
          <h1 class="dfHeader" style={{left:'30px'}}>
          DataFrames :<br></br></h1>
          <h1  class='dfHeader2'style={{top:'150px',left:'30px'}}>
          constructor</h1>

          <div class="codeBorder" style={{scrollbarColor:'#6a00ff'}}>
          <div class="textbox" style={{width:'180px'}}>
          <p class="instructions"></p>
          <p class="instructions2"></p>

          <p class="instructions3">
          <form class="codeForm">
            <label>
            enter dimensions:
            <input type="number" name="dimension" onKeyUp=
            {e => setCol(e.target.value)} />
            </label>
              <input class='goButton' type="submit" value="run" />
          </form>
            <br/><br/></p>
          <p class="instructions3">
          <form class="codeForm">
            <label>
            input code:
              <input type="number" name="dimension" />
            </label>
              <input class='goButton' type="submit" value="run" />
          </form></p>
          <p class="instructions3">
          <form class="codeForm">
            <label>
            input code:
              <input type="number" name="dimension" />
            </label>
              <input class='goButton' type="submit" value="run" />
          </form></p>
          <p class="instructions3">
          <form class="codeForm">
            <label>
            input code:
              <input type="number" name="dimension" />
            </label>
              <input class='goButton' type="submit" value="run" />
          </form> </p>

          </div>
          </div>

          <div class="btnConsole">
            <button class="dfButton" onClick={()=>setToggle( (prev) => (!prev) )}>
            </button>
          </div>
          </div>

          <div class="monitor"style={{}}>
          <div class="superScreen">
            <div class="screenDiv" >
              <div id="subScreen" class="subScreen">

                {[...Array(col).keys()].map(ul => (
                  <ul key={ul}>
                    {toggle &&
                      [...Array(row).keys()].map(
                        li => <Element key={li} />)}
                  </ul>
                ))}

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
        <br/>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default DataFrame;

ReactDOM.render(<DataFrame />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Any help is appreciated as always!

Comment: what does your desired array looks like?

Comment: my desired array is n by whatever the input number is. It is an array of list elements. so if i set "row" to 9, and the user enters 5 in the form, the array would be a 9 x 5 array of list elements.

Comment: was just about to edit my response to add that : ) currently, row is set to 3, and if i input any number, i just get a 1 x 3 array.

Comment: added the actual code block : )

Comment: Do you mean you want to set the function parameter in the above question, first line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
onKeyUp={e => setCol(e.target.value)}
```

this is the cause of your problem. `e.target.value` is a string, you are setting `col` equal to a `string`. Consequently, `[...Array(col).keys()]` gives you an array of length 1.

```js
const col = '5';
console.log([...Array(col).keys()]);
```

Change

```
onKeyUp={e => setCol(e.target.value)}
```

to

```
onKeyUp={e => setCol(Number(e.target.value))}
```